# why I get an error on Thread-1 when running my python program from an .exe file with a Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python

I design a GUI with `Tkinter` and also I add a function to convert a .docx file to .PDF file with the docx2pdf library.

I execute the main function of my python code in a Thread because when I run my code from the .exe file the GUI is locked (like it freezes).

I add an event to a button to run the main function in a new thread.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from threading import *
from docx2pdf import convert

def mProcess():
  input = "C:\\test.docx"
  output = "C:\\file.pdf"
  convert(input,output)


def mainTask():
   t = Thread(target=mProcess)
   t.daemon = True
   t.start()


### GUI

win = Tk()

ttk.Button(win, text = 'Start', command = mainTask).pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

If I run this code from my VS code it runs well. The problem only happens when I generate the .exe file of my code and run it.

I generate the exe file with `pyinstaller test.py --onefile --windowed`.

The error I get when run from the exe file:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
pywintypes.como_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "threading.py", line 973, in bootstrap_inner
File "threading.py", line 910, in run
```

Comment: Does the problem occur when the script has not been converted to an .exe?

Comment: No, only occur when convert my script to .exe, if I run the code on my IDE it works perfect

Comment: first you could add some `print()` to see which commands are executed before erorr. Python wasn't created to built .exe and programs like `PyInstaller` may have problem to find all needed Python modules and C/C++ libraries and it needs to add them manually to file `.spec` which PyInstaller` uses for configuration. In PyInstaller you can find pages `Using Spec File` and `What to do when something went wrong`.